# How to create a square matrix with 2 inputs each having "n" values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**Question:** The domain of the function is a square x1,x2 belongs to [-2,2). In order to form the training set, sample the  functions on  a  regular  32×32grid.

I want to create this and then evaluate 2 functions (outputs): y1 & y2 which are some function of x1,x2.

I've tried the following as a test, but I'm unable to a get a square grid/matrix:`

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.linspace(-2,2,5)
x2 = np.linspace(-2,2,5)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1,x2)
print(X1,X2)
```

AND

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
x1 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 4, endpoint=False)
print(x1)
x2 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 4, endpoint=False)
print(x2)
number=1
for combination in itertools.product(x1,x2):
  print(number,combination)
  number+=1
```

But am unable to get the way I want it.
Once I get the input matrix, how do I get the output matrix from it given the functions y1 & y2?
I need it further to create a NN, but can't get the first step right.
Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the output of the meshgrid approach?

Comment: For my original question I should be getting a 32x32 input matrix, right? 
Or am I interpreting it wrong? 
I basically need to sample the functions/outputs (y1 & y2) over a 32x32 grid, so I thought I should first create an input grid with x1 & x2, but maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: Or do I need to do factorial design (I came across it just now) to create 32x32 pairs of values for (x1,x2) like the 2nd code using itertools.product ? And then somehow get the corresponding pairs for (y1,y2)?

Comment: If you are using the meshgrid approach and change the `np.linspace(-2,2,5)` to `np.linspace(-2,2,32)` you should get 32x32 grids.